# Link facebook login to existing account swift with firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to sign in with facebook and if there is existing account I want to merge it. I achieve that for apple and google login. When I try with facebook I had this error:  `An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address`.  All my logic for the facebook flow is inside the `SignInFacebookHelper`  here is how I get the token in the `LoginViewModel`:

```
func signInFacebook() async throws {
        let helper = SignInFacebookHelper()
        let tokens = try await helper.startSignInWithFacebookFlow()
        try await AuthenticationManager.shared.signInWithFacebook(tokens: tokens as! SignInWithFacebookResult)
    }
```

Here is the logic in my `AuthenticationManager`:

```
@discardableResult
    func signInWithFacebook(tokens: SignInWithFacebookResult) async throws -> AuthDataResultModel {
        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: tokens.accessToken)
        return try await signIn(credential: credential)
    }
```

Here is my SignInFacebookHelper:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FacebookLogin

struct SignInWithFacebookResult {
    let accessToken: String
    let nonce: String
}

@MainActor
final class SignInFacebookHelper: NSObject {
    private var completionHandler: ((Result<SignInWithFacebookResult, Error>) -> Void)? = nil

    func startSignInWithFacebookFlow() async throws -> SignInWithFacebookResult {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            self.startSignInWithFacebookFlow { result in
                print("Result!!!")
                print(result)
                switch result {
                case .success(let signInFacebookResult):
                    continuation.resume(returning: signInFacebookResult)
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func startSignInWithFacebookFlow(completion: @escaping (Result<SignInWithFacebookResult, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let topVC = Utilities.shared.topViewController() else {
            completion(.failure(URLError(.badURL)))
            return
        }

        completionHandler = completion
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(permissions: ["email"], from: topVC) { [weak self] result, error in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            if let error = error {
                print("Facebook login failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else if let result = result, !result.isCancelled {
                guard let accessToken = result.token?.tokenString else {
                    completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "YourAppDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to obtain Facebook access token"])))
                    return
                }
                let nonce = randomNonceString()
                let tokens = SignInWithFacebookResult(accessToken: accessToken, nonce: nonce)
                completion(.success(tokens))
            } else {
                // Handle other scenarios (e.g., user cancelled)
                completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "YourAppDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "User cancelled Facebook login"])))
            }
        }
    }

    private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
        precondition(length > 0)
        var randomBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
        let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, randomBytes.count, &randomBytes)
        if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
            fatalError(
                "Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)"
            )
        }

        let charset: [Character] =
        Array("RaNdOmStRiNg")

        let nonce = randomBytes.map { byte in
            // Pick a random character from the set, wrapping around if needed.
            charset[Int(byte) % charset.count]
        }

        return String(nonce)
    }
}
```

I read many related articles but nothing helped I checked this answer:
[In firebase login getting error "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials" in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975207/in-firebase-login-getting-error-an-account-already-exists-with-the-same-email-a)
I am sure that option enables me because I already have accounts with multiple login providers.

I read the documentation as well:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking